# Angular 5 - Component Having multiple child component with MAT-AUTOCOMPLETE is slowing down typing

Tags: angular

I have a parent component with many child components having MAT-AUTOCOMPLETE. After navigating the fields having autocomplete slowing down the typing speed on full form.

Thanks in advance.

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <form autocomplete="off" id="airwaybillForm" name="airwaybillForm" method="POST" action="javascript: void(0);" jhiFormFieldsChangesDetector jhiFormReset="awbprefix" [formGroup]="airwaybillForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitAirwaybill();">
            <div>
                <jhi-header-buttons [form]="airwaybillForm"></jhi-header-buttons>
            </div>

            <mat-card class="aci-sample-card">
                <mat-card-content class="aci-sample-content">
                    <div class="row custom-mat-card-header">
                        <div class="col-12 default-row-height">
                            <mat-card-header>
                                <mat-card-title>Master Airway Bill Details</mat-card-title>
                            </mat-card-header>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4 custom-awbnumber">
                            <mat-form-field>
                                <jhi-awbnumber-search
                                    [awbnumberGroup]="airwaybillForm.controls.awbnumberGroup"
                                    [isFormSubmitted]="isFormSubmitted"
                                    [isFormFieldMarkAsTouched]="isFormFieldMarkAsTouched"
                                    [isFormFieldsEnabled]="isFormFieldsEnabled"
                                    (isFormFieldsEnabledEmitter)="isFormFieldsEnabledChange($event)"
                                    [formControlAwbprefixName]="'awbprefix'"
                                    [formControlAwbprefixValue]="formControlAwbprefixValue"
                                    [formControlAwbnumberName]="'awbnumber'"
                                    [formControlAwbnumberValue]="formControlAwbnumberValue"
                                    [fieldChangeShowConfirmationDialog]="true"
                                    [isAwbPrefixFieldInvalid]="isAwbPrefixFieldInvalid"
                                    [isRequired]="true"
                                    placeholder="Airway Bill Number">
                                </jhi-awbnumber-search>

                                <mat-icon matSuffix class="forward-search-icon">
                                    <a href="javascript: void(0);" (click)="searchAirwayBill(airwaybillForm.get('awbnumberGroup.awbprefix').value, airwaybillForm.get('awbnumberGroup.awbnumber').value); $event.stopPropagation();">arrow_forward</a>
                                </mat-icon>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-4">
                            <jhi-origin-search
                                [fieldId]="'origin'"
                                [fieldName]="'origin'"
                                [fieldPlaceholder]="'Origin'"
                                [originGroup]="airwaybillForm.controls.originGroup"
                                [isFormSubmitted]="isFormSubmitted"
                                [compareWithFieldValue]="airwaybillForm.get('destinationGroup.destination').value"
                                [formControlFieldName]="'origin'"
                                [isRequired]="true">
                            </jhi-origin-search>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-4">
                            <jhi-destination-search
                                [fieldId]="'destination'"
                                [fieldName]="'destination'"
                                [fieldPlaceholder]="'Destination'"
                                [destinationGroup]="airwaybillForm.controls.destinationGroup"
                                [isFormSubmitted]="isFormSubmitted"
                                [compareWithFieldValue]="airwaybillForm.get('originGroup.origin').value"
                                [formControlFieldName]="'destination'"
                                [isRequired]="true">
                            </jhi-destination-search>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <jhi-pieces
                                [fieldId]="'pieces'"
                                [fieldName]="'pieces'"
                                [fieldPlaceholder]="'Pieces'"
                                [piecesGroup]="airwaybillForm.controls.piecesGroup"
                                [formControlFieldName]="'pieces'"
                                [isFormSubmitted]="isFormSubmitted"
                                [maxLength]="4"
                                [isRequired]="true"
                                [isReadOnly]="false">
                            </jhi-pieces>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-4">
                            <jhi-weight
                                [fieldId]="'weight'"
                                [fieldName]="'weight'"
                                [fieldPlaceholder]="'Weight'"
                                [weightGroup]="airwaybillForm.controls.weightGroup"
                                [formControlFieldName]="'weight'"
                                [isFormSubmitted]="isFormSubmitted"
                                [format]="'5,2'"
                                [maxLength]="8"
                                [isRequired]="true"
                                [isReadOnly]="false">
                            </jhi-weight>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-4">
                            <jhi-volume
                                [fieldId]="'volume'"
                                [fieldName]="'volume'"
                                [fieldPlaceholder]="'Volume'"
                                [volumeGroup]="airwaybillForm.controls.volumeGroup"
                                [formControlFieldName]="'volume'"
                                [isFormSubmitted]="isFormSubmitted"
                                [format]="'7,2'"
                                [maxLength]="10"
                                [isRequired]="true"
                                [isReadOnly]="false">
                            </jhi-volume>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <jhi-customer-search
                                [fieldId]="'customer'"
                                [fieldName]="'customer'"
                                [fieldPlaceholder]="'Customer'"
                                [customerGroup]="airwaybillForm.controls.customerGroup"
                                [isFormSubmitted]="isFormSubmitted"
                                [formControlFieldName]="'customer'"
                                [maxLength]="40"
                                [isRequired]="true"
                                (consigneeDetail)="populateConsignee($event);">
                            </jhi-customer-search>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <jhi-shc-codes
                                [fieldId]="'shcCodes'"
                                [fieldName]="'shcCodes'"
                                [fieldPlaceholder]="'SHC'"
                                [shcCodesGroup]="airwaybillForm.controls.shcCodesGroup"
                                [isFormSubmitted]="isFormSubmitted"
                                [formControlFieldName]="'shcCodes'"
                                [fieldShcCodes]="airwaybillForm.get('shcCodesGroup.shcCodes').value"
                                [isSearched]="isSearched"
                                [maxChipsAllowed]="9"
                                (isSearchedFalse)="isSearchedFalse($event);"
                                [isRequired]="false"
                                [isDisabled]="airwaybillForm.get('shcCodesGroup.shcCodes').disabled"
                                [isRemovable]="isCreateMode">
                            </jhi-shc-codes>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

All fields on parent html are child component. I am posting 1 child component code as well below, all other child component have almost similar code.

**Customer Component - jhi-customer-search [HTML]**

```
<div [formGroup]="customerGroup">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input
            id="{{fieldId ? fieldId : 'customer'}}"
            name="{{fieldName ? fieldName : 'customer'}}"
            type="text"
            placeholder="{{fieldPlaceholder ? fieldPlaceholder : 'Customer'}}"
            (input)="searchCustomer($event.target.value);"
            matInput
            class="text-overflow-ellipsis uppercase"
            title="{{fieldPlaceholder ? fieldPlaceholder : 'Customer'}}"
            formControlName="{{formControlFieldName ? formControlFieldName : 'customer'}}"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            [required]="isRequired"
            maxlength="{{maxLength}}"
            [readonly]="isReadOnly"
            (focus)="isFocusOut = false; focusManager(true);"
            (focusout)="isFocusOut = true; focusManager(false);"
            autocomplete="off"
        />
        <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors[formControlFieldName]">
            {{formErrors[formControlFieldName]}}
        </mat-error>

        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='selectCustomer($event.option.value);' autoActiveFirstOption>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer">
                {{customer.userName}} - {{customer.companyName}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**Customer Component [.ts Script]**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, HostListener, EventEmitter, Output, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomerService } from './customer.service';
import { CommonService, CUSTOMER_SEARCH_MIN_LENGTH } from '../../../shared';
import { Subscription } from '../../../../../../../node_modules/rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-customer-search',
    templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
})
export class CustomerSearchComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    @Input() customerGroup: FormGroup;
    @Input() isFormSubmitted: boolean;
    @Input() isRequired: boolean;
    @Input() fieldId: string;
    @Input() fieldName: string;
    @Input() fieldPlaceholder: string;
    @Input() isReadOnly = false;
    @Input() formControlFieldName: string;
    @Input() maxLength: number;
    @Output() consigneeDetail: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    auto: any;
    customers: any;
    validationMessages: any;
    formErrors = [];
    isFocusOut = false;
    isCustomerSelected = true;
    CUSTOMER_SEARCH_MIN_LENGTH = CUSTOMER_SEARCH_MIN_LENGTH;
    getCustomersSubscriptions: Subscription;
    constructor(
        private commonService: CommonService,
        private customerService: CustomerService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.validationMessages = {
            [this.formControlFieldName]: {
                required: 'Please enter customer name.'
            }
        };
    }

    @HostListener('change') ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.isFormSubmitted) {
            this.customerGroup.get('customer').markAsTouched();
            this.focusManager(false);
        }
        this.checkValidations();
    }

    focusManager(isFocusIn = null) {
        if (isFocusIn === true) {
            this.customers = [];
            this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).setValidators([]);
        }

        if (isFocusIn === false) {
            this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).setValidators([]);
            if (this.isRequired) {
                this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).setValidators([Validators.required]);
            }

            // checking length if it is less than the required then remove it automatically and on focus out check if searched data available then select top option automatically
            const searchText = this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).value;
            if (searchText && searchText.length < this.CUSTOMER_SEARCH_MIN_LENGTH) {
                this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).setValue(null);
                this.customerGroup.get('selectedCustomer').setValue(null);
            } else if (this.isCustomerSelected === false && this.customers && this.customers[0] && this.customers[0].companyName) {
                this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).setValue(this.customers[0].companyName.toUpperCase());
                this.customerGroup.get('selectedCustomer').setValue(this.customers[0]);
                this.consigneeDetail.emit(this.customers[0]);
                this.isCustomerSelected = true;
            }
        }
        this.checkValidations();
    }

    checkValidations() {
        this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).updateValueAndValidity();
        this.formErrors = this.commonService.getFormValidationErrors(this.customerGroup, this.validationMessages, this.formErrors);
    }

    selectCustomer(selectedCustomer = null) {
        if (selectedCustomer) {
            this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).setValue(selectedCustomer.companyName.toUpperCase());
            this.customerGroup.get('selectedCustomer').setValue(selectedCustomer);
            this.consigneeDetail.emit(selectedCustomer);
            this.isCustomerSelected = true;
        }

        if (this.isCustomerSelected === false) {
            if (this.customers && this.customers[0] && this.customers[0].companyName) {
                this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).setValue(this.customers[0].companyName.toUpperCase());
                this.customerGroup.get('selectedCustomer').setValue(this.customers[0]);
                this.consigneeDetail.emit(this.customers[0]);
                this.isCustomerSelected = true;
            } else {
                this.customerGroup.get(this.formControlFieldName).setValue(null);
                this.customerGroup.get('selectedCustomer').setValue(null);
                this.isCustomerSelected = false;
                this.focusManager(false);
            }
            this.unSubscribeServices();
        }
    }

    searchCustomer(searchText) {
        this.isCustomerSelected = false;
        this.unSubscribeServices();
        this.customers = [];
        if (searchText.length >= this.CUSTOMER_SEARCH_MIN_LENGTH) {
            this.getCustomersSubscriptions = this.customerService.getCustomers(searchText).subscribe((response) => {
                const custometrsDetails = response['details'];
                if (custometrsDetails) {
                    custometrsDetails.forEach((customer) => {
                        if ((customer.userName && customer.companyName) || customer.wknCCode) {
                            this.customers.push({
                                'ccCode': customer.ccCode,
                                'companyName': customer.wknCCode ? 'WALKIN CUSTOMER' : customer.companyName,
                                'userName': customer.wknCCode ? 'WALKIN' : customer.userName,
                                'accountCode': customer.accountCode,
                                'companyCode': customer.wknCCode ? 'WLKIN' : customer.companyCode,
                                'customercode': customer.wknCCode ? 'WALKIN' : customer.customercode,
                                'street': customer.street,
                                'place': customer.place,
                                'countryCode': customer.countryCode,
                                'email': customer.email,
                                'mobile': customer.mobile,
                                'phone': customer.phone
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    if (this.isFocusOut) {
                        this.selectCustomer();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    unSubscribeServices() {
        if (this.getCustomersSubscriptions) {
            this.getCustomersSubscriptions.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.unSubscribeServices();
    }
}
```

I have tried with removed [matAutocomplete]="auto" from all my child component and it works perfectly without any slowness issue.

Comment: I don't see any code. Could you post an example? [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info on MCVE.

Comment: Thanks Dean for your quick reply, i have added the code. slow typing issue getting started when i am navigating parent fields many times.
appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Awaiting for some expert advise, please let me know if more details required.